# How to prevent no selection in QTableWidget?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a QTableWidget with some rows in it. I want selection to be always present. But once I click somewhere on the Table outside the rows I lose my selection. Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: First an MRE would be nice -- but my first question (since their is no MRE) is do you actually lose your selection (aka did you check your "selected" value for the list) or do you just lose the focus on your selection?  The former can be fixed by storing a value of the last selected item every time something is selected and the former is just a matter of focus or a visual representation that a line is still selected -- or a combination of the former and the latter.

Comment: I select rows,click on the table space without rows and get selectedItems = [ ]. Nothing is selected. But when I select items and then click on different widget I just lose focus.

Comment: Okay as stated then just capture what was last selected and store it and then refer to that variable rather than the list.  Of course you might want to highlight the row to indicate that it has been selected and is still selected.  So my next question (because I have encountered this) once something has been selected how does one get back to the original state where nothing has been selected?

Comment: Answer for next question : Once I select something and click on empty space below selected rows on QTableWidget I lose my selection.

Comment: Okay but you stated you did not want that to happen. So once a row has been set up properly and selected you stated you wanted it to always remain selected -- my question was if you do this -- how does the user go back to a non-selected state or is that something that should not ever happen?  If it should never happen then the list should start out selected with whatever default you feel is most appropriate.  So all I am saying with this is --- since I outlined how to keep it selected -- is that you need to consider the -- now that it is always selected will the user ever want it not selected?

Comment: First first row can be selected. It is easy to do so. Then when user selects other rows it will be other selection. But It must not be no selection at all. It have to be some selection. I remember it was such function in tkinter. But I cannot find it in PyQt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to ensure that an item exists at the coordinates the user clicks in.
This can be done by ensuring that `QTableWidget.indexAt(pos)` returns a *valid* index: if it is, it means that an item exists there, so we can proceed with the base class `mousePressEvent`, otherwise we just ignore it.

```
class AlwaysSelectedTable(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.indexAt(event.pos()).isValid():
            QtWidgets.QTableWidget.mousePressEvent(self, event)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This solution really helped me.